# Unwanted line breaks after equation tag when using fleqn and leqno

Tags: equations, line-breaking, amsmath

When you use `fleqn` and `leqno` and assign your own equations tags with `\tag` to equations in environments such as `gather` and `align` and you assign a tag with a certain length, then there's a line break after the tag. Given the same condition except that environment `equation` is used instead does not cause line breaks. How can I avoid the line breaks in the former case?

[image: Example of the problem]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \tag{one}
  1+1=2 \\
  \tag{two}
  2+2=4
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
  \tag{three}
  1+1=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAIK, you shouldn't use both `fleqn` and `leqno`.

Comment: @egreg Could you please provide a reference for why I should avoid it? Also, is there some recommended way of getting a similar result?

Comment: I see very little point in putting the number on the left of left aligned equations. Of course, if you really want to do it, you have to set `\mathindent` as wide as necessary in order to accommodate all your tags and leave sufficient space to avoid ambiguities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase `\mathindent`, but I don't know why you want to use `fleqn` and `leqno` simultaneously:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\mathindent{2cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \tag{one}
  1+1=2 \\
  \tag{two}
  2+2=4
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
  \tag{three}
  1+1=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I use `fleqn` and `leqno` because I want to flush equations to the left and also have equation numbers to the left. Is this bad practice?

Comment: @N.N. But then, the equation number could be cause some confusion as it could be taken, if it falls too close to an equation, as part of the equation.

Comment: Why is `\setlength\mathindent` needed for `gather` but not for `equation`?

Comment: @N.N. perhaps you can consider opening a new question.